# Execute DELETE only when the SELECT returns

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I have a routine where I update the local database with other database data.

I only execute a **DELETE** and then an **INSERT INTO tblX (SELECT * FROM tblY (tblY is a linked table))**, as below.

The problem is that, in some cases the **SELECT** takes a long time after the **DELETE** and I´d like to diminish the possibility of the user to make a request to this table while it´s processing.

I´d like to know if there is some mechanism to execute the **DELETE** only after the return of the **SELECT**.

```
conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexaoPainelGerencialLocal());

conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" DELETE * FROM tblClienteContato; ", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd = new OleDbCommand(" INSERT INTO tblClienteContato " +
                       " SELECT * FROM tblClienteContatoVinculada;", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg commented, I created temporary tables to receive data from the external database and then I tranfer the data to the definitive tables, so that the probability of the users being impacted is very low.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you need to do is wrap both of those commands in a transaction.

The cool thing about a transaction is that it either **ALL WORKS** or **ALL FAILS**, meaning that if something happens to stop the select statement, the database will not finalise the delete statement.

This looks like a really good example to work with:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ehy0z8(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that they have one command object, and replace the CommandText, rather than create a new object each time. This is probably important.

Try something like this:

```
conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexaoPainelGerencialLocal());
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbTransaction transaction = null;

try {

    conn.Open();
    transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;



    cmd.CommandText = " DELETE * FROM tblClienteContato; ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO tblClienteContato " +
                       " SELECT * FROM tblClienteContatoVinculada;";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // The data isn't _finally_ completed until this happens
    transaction.Commit();


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Something has gone wrong.
    // do whatever error messaging you do
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    try
    {
        // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
        // this means your records won't be deleted
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do nothing here; transaction is not active.
    }
}
```

Comment: Greg, I´m getting the following message when executting  the "BeginTransaction": "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported"

Comment: Try it with no parameter in there? Access & Jet probably don't support isolation level.

Comment: Another option would be to do this in two stages, using a temporary table.  DELETE from the temp table (that no one ever uses), do the slow INSERT into the temp table. When that completes, DELETE from the main table, and do an INSERT into the main table, but select from your local temp table (which should be fast) instead of the remote one.  This means that the time that the main table is busy should be much shorter.

Comment: Great Greg. This is exactly what I did. All the transaction commands returned the message "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported", so that I created temp tables. Put it as answer....

Answer (score 0):

You should look into BeginTransaction, Commit and rollback, here's an example:

```
    _con.Open();
    _con_trans = _con.BeginTransaction();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = _con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from XXXXX";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Transaction = _con_trans;
        cmd.ExecuteNonquery();
    }

    using(SqlCommand cmd = _con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into XXXX";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Transaction = _con_trans;
        cmd.ExecuteNonquery();
    }
    _con_trans.Commit();
    _con_trans = null;
    _con.Close();
```

This way, everything is wrapped under a single transaction, so when the delete begins, the table will be locked for reading and writing.

Comment: Alex, I´m getting the following message when executting the "BeginTransaction": "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported"

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the schema of the table, it is hard to identify why the delete process is taking an extended amount of time.

An alternative to wrapping the commands within a transaction would be to simply delete the table itself rather than the data within it by using the `DROP TABLE` command. And then you can recreate the table utilizing the `SELECT...INTO...FROM` statement to recreate. A potential advantage to this is that the schemas will match identically, and any inherent conversions (eg decimal to int) will not need to be done.

```
    using (conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexaoPainelGerencialLocal())) {
        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE tblClienteContato; ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO tblClienteContato FROM tblClienteContatoVinculada;";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

**The following does not apply here (MS Access), but may to other SQL variants**
Another option is to utilize the `TRUNCATE` command, which will delete everything in the table in one fell swoop. There is no logging of the individual rows and the indexes (if present) don't need to be recalculated on each and every line being deleted. The catch to this method is that this will not work within the transaction. If there is an Identity column the value will be reset as well. There are other potential cons to this but without knowing the design of the table I have no way of identifying them.

```
using (conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexaoPainelGerencialLocal())) {
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()) {

        cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE tblClienteContato; ";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO tblClienteContato " +
            " SELECT * FROM tblClienteContatoVinculada;";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mad, I continue having the problem with the delay on the select command. 

After deleting the data from the table it takes a long time to get the new date in the select.

Comment: What happens if you run this within MS Access?